# The origin of words 콩쥐, 팥쥐

Tags: word-origin

There is a Korean story whose title is 콩쥐 팥쥐

Even though I do not know the ending of the story, it is very
similar to 신데델라 Sindedella : 팥쥐 is a daughter of step mother.

Question : What are meanings of 콩쥐, 팥쥐 ?

1) 콩=bean=soybean

팥=adzuki bean=red bean=It is a bean of red color whose taste is
sugary.

**2) 콩쥐? a mouse eating beans ?**

The reason that I think such is as follows :
  There is a similar word comparing to 콩쥐.

다람쥐 = squirrel. 다람 = 다름질 = 담박질 = 달리기 = run ?
   That is, 다람쥐 is a running
  mouse ?

[add] There are proverbs related to soybean and red bean.
 Accordingly, 콩, 팥 are familiar to us.

콩 심은 데 콩 나고, 팥 심은 데 팥 난다.

=There is no red bean where we scatter seeds of soybean

=An onion will not produce a rose.

팥으로 메주를 쑨대도 곧이듣는다

=I believe that they make block of fermented soybeans with red beans

=be gulliblefall for anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

쥐 = mouse, definetly.
But 쥐 in 콩쥐 is not meaning of mouse.
In old korean days,

조이 was most popular female's name.

콩조이 => 콩쥐,

팥조이 => 팥쥐.